# Add the name of the file to the combined csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python. I have a set of CSV files, and I was able to combine them into one file using

```
os.chdir("../Stok list")

extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
combined_csv.to_csv( "../combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

However, I need to add the name of the file (in each row) to the data, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
os.chdir("../Stok list")

extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

combined_csv = []
for f in all_filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    df['filename'] = [f] * len(df.index)
    combined_csv.append(df)
combined_csv = pd.concat(combined_csv)
combined_csv.to_csv( "../combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

It should add a column named `filename` to your final csv. Note that if your original file has incompatible columns or a column named `filename` the code will fail or behave in some strange unexpected way.

Comment: @Tman if the answer helped you remember to accept it by clicking on the mark symbol, so that other people looking for the same answer know this method works :-)