# Adding a conditional column to the data

Tags: python, pandas

In my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69162969/10611557) - I added a column with the name of the file as it was suggested, using this information I wanted to add a date that corresponds to the file like so

```
os.chdir("../Stok list")
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

combined_csv = []
for f in all_filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    df['filename'] = [f] * len(df.index)
    if [f] == '1 Sept 21.csv':
        df['Date_of_file'] == datetime.strptime('01/09/2021', '%d/%m/%Y') * len(df.index)
    elif [f] == '2 Sept 21.csv':
        df['Date_of_file'] == datetime.strptime('02/09/2021', '%d/%m/%Y') * len(df.index)
    elif [f] == '3 Sept 21.csv':
        df['Date_of_file'] == datetime.strptime('03/09/2021', '%d/%m/%Y') * len(df.index)
    elif [f] == '6 Sept 21.csv':
        df['Date_of_file'] == datetime.strptime('06/09/2021', '%d/%m/%Y') * len(df.index)
    elif [f] == '7 Sept 21.csv':
        df['Date_of_file'] == datetime.strptime('07/09/2021', '%d/%m/%Y') * len(df.index)
    elif [f] == '8 Sept 21.csv':
        df['Date_of_file'] == datetime.strptime('08/09/2021', '%d/%m/%Y') * len(df.index)
    elif [f] == '9 Sept 21.csv':
        df['Date_of_file'] == datetime.strptime('09/09/2021', '%d/%m/%Y') * len(df.index)
    elif [f] == '10 Sept 21.csv':
        df['Date_of_file'] == datetime.strptime('10/09/2021', '%d/%m/%Y') * len(df.index)
    elif [f] == '13 Sept 21.csv':
        df['Date_of_file'] == datetime.strptime('13/09/2021', '%d/%m/%Y') * len(df.index)
    else:
        df['Date_of_file'] == 'No date'
    combined_csv.append(df)


combined_csv = pd.concat(combined_csv)
combined_csv.to_csv( "../combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

However, this is not working at all

Comment: `[f] == '1 Sept 21.csv'`. The **list** containing `f` will _never_ be equal to a **string**.

Comment: Also, `df['Date_of_file'] == datetime.strptime('09/09/2021', '%d/%m/%Y') * len(df.index)` doesn't assign anything. `==` is equality check

Comment: Yes, I was stupid. I have changed `==` to `=` and `[f]` to `f`, I also removed `* len(df.index)` and that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a lengthy `if/elif` could you not extract the date from the filename then use `pd.to_datetime`?

```py
df['date_of_file'] = pd.to_datetime(df['filename'].str[:-4].str.replace('Sept', 'Sep'),format = '%d %b %y')
```

Note, I've had to replace `Sept` with `Sep` as `Sep` is the recognised abbreviation for `September`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I would like to know how can I incorporate that is I also had date like '1 October 21'? Will I need an if statement?